# Hiding pure virtual method in template class for some template parameters for compilation purpose

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

With template classes, C++ allows that you add methods that won't compile for some template parameter provided that you do not call that specific method on an instance with the wrong template parameter.

```
template<typename T>
class B 
{
public :
    int foo()  {return 5;}
    int bar()
    {
     T v;
     return v;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    B<int> b1;
    b1.foo();
    b1.bar(); // this line compiles
    B<string> b2;
    b2.foo();
    //b2.bar(); this line won't compile
}
```

Now suppose that `class B` has a base class where `bar()` is a virtual method

```
template<typename T>
class A {
public :
    virtual int foo() =0;
    virtual int bar() =0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public :
    int foo() override {return 5;}
    int bar() override
    {
     T v;
     return v;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    B<int> b1;
    b1.foo();
    b1.bar();
    B<string> b2; // instanciation not allowed
    b2.foo();
}
```

This code won't compile. The reason is clear : `B<string>` derives from `A<string>` that exposes a `bar()` virtual method.

But, actually I have no intention to call bar() as far as the instanciated type is `string`. So I would like to somewhat tell the compiler that `A::bar()` exists only for `int` template type.

What would be the cleanest way to deal with that issue ?

Comment: The cleanest way is a redesign. A virtual function must be instantiated for dynamic dispatch to work, because by the very nature of run time polymorphism, the compiler has no way to vet a call won't actually ever happen.

Comment: Something along `virtual int bar() =0 requires (std::is_same_v<T, int>);`? But strange interface then...

Comment: Specialize `A` for `int` as template parameter. Of course you need to specialize `B` too, since `override` results in a compile time error otherwise (in addition to the problems you mentioned in the question)...

Comment: I see template classes as a practical way to create set of independent classes. B<int> derives from A<int> but has no link with A<string> or B<string>. The fact that A<string>::bar() and B<string>::bar() do not exist is not a problem for the compiler. It would be the case if A was not templated itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure it's the *best* way to handle it, but you can handle this with explicit specialization:

```cpp
#include <string>

template<typename T>
class A {
public :
    virtual int foo() =0;
};

template <>
class A<int> {
public:
    virtual int foo() = 0;
    virtual int bar() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class B : public A<T>
{
public :
    int foo() override {return 5;}
};

template <>
class B<int> : public A<int> {
public:
    int foo() override { return 5; }
    int bar() override { return 1; }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    B<int> b1;
    b1.foo();
    b1.bar();
    B<std::string> b2; // instanciation now allowed
    b2.foo();
}
```

I'm not sure this really accomplishes a great deal though. In particular, the *usual* reason for using inheritance is to allow you to use a (possibly smart) pointer to the base class to work with objects of derived classes. But in this case, `A<int>` is a completely separate type from `A<std::string>`, so you can't have something like a collection of `A *`, some of which refer to objects of type `B<int>` and others to `B<std::string>` (and so on), and then invoke virtual functions on those derived objects.

On the other hand, you *could* also have other a class `C<T>` that also derives from `A<T>` and then have a collection of `A<T> *` that could point to either a `B<T>` or a `C<T>` (for the same type `T` throughout) and invoke virtual functions on all of them.

Comment: *"So I would like to somewhat tell the compiler that A::bar() exists only for int template type."* This means the specialization should happen for `A<int>` and `B<int>` instead...

Comment: @fabian: Oops--quite right.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, (I have oversimplified the problem in my post) the actual class that would need to be specialized is quite big and specializing it would require to duplicate everything. So I've tried to specialize the method that is only useful for template parameter int so that it return -1 for other types. Unfortunately, it still does not compile as my class has 2 template arguments and you can not partially specialize a method... I think I should look at C++17 features like constexpr that I wanted to avoid because I am not familiar with.